# Unable to fetch query formula results between 2 dates using sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet where I need to filter the rows based on 2 dates B1 and B2.
I have tried with the formula

[Make a copy of the worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C69Ha1NRQU7qk4G6ag2-J_-g1PNwz4eNLD2JXRwjrIs/copy)

[To view the worksheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1C69Ha1NRQU7qk4G6ag2-J_-g1PNwz4eNLD2JXRwjrIs)

[image]

```
=QUERY(arrayformula({IFERROR(DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(Work_Hours2019!A1:C,"SELECT A"), "\w+ \d{2}, \d{4}")) + TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(QUERY(Work_Hours2019!A1:C,"SELECT A"), "\d{2}:\d{2}[A|P]M$"))),QUERY(Work_Hours2019!A1:C,"SELECT B, C")}), "SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col1 > date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(B1),"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works

```
=FILTER (Work_Hours2019!A1:C, datevalue(REGEXREPLACE(Work_Hours2019!A1:A, " at (.*)$",))>=B1, datevalue(REGEXREPLACE(Work_Hours2019!A1:A, " at (.*)$",))<=B2)
```

[image]